# How to pass post request parameters in Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle18c

I have a cURL command as shown below:

```
curl --insecure -X POST https://www.example.com -H 'accept-encoding: gzip,deflate' -H 'cache-control: no-cache' -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' --data "request_type=secure&scope=global&user_id=temp&password=temppass"
```

I'm not sure, how I need to invoke this POST request from within a PL/SQL procedure.

Especially I don't know how to pass the --data parameters.

```
DECLARE
    http_request    UTL_HTTP.req;
    http_response   UTL_HTTP.resp;
    return_text VARCHAR2(2000);
BEGIN
    http_request := UTL_HTTP.begin_request('https://www.example.com/path/sub_path');

    UTL_HTTP.set_header(http_request, 'accept-encoding', 'gzip,deflate');
    UTL_HTTP.set_header(http_request, 'cache-control', 'no-cache');
    UTL_HTTP.set_header(http_request, 'content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    UTL_HTTP.set_authentication(http_request, 'temp', 'temppass');

    http_response := UTL_HTTP.get_response(http_request);

    UTL_HTTP.read_text(http_response, return_text);
    dbms_output.put_line (return_text);
END;
/
```

Please could anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your first statement where you are building the request, you declare the HTTP method.

```
http_request := UTL_HTTP.begin_request('https://www.example.com/path/sub_path','POST');
```

An example on how to send a request with a body can be found [here](https://technology.amis.nl/2015/05/11/invoke-a-rest-service-from-plsql-make-an-http-post-request-using-utl_http-in-oracle-database-11g-xe/)

Example of your code:

```
DECLARE
    http_request    UTL_HTTP.req;
    http_response   UTL_HTTP.resp;
    return_text     VARCHAR2 (2000);
BEGIN
    http_request := UTL_HTTP.begin_request ('https://www.example.com/path/sub_path', 'POST');

    UTL_HTTP.set_header (http_request, 'accept-encoding', 'gzip,deflate');
    UTL_HTTP.set_header (http_request, 'cache-control', 'no-cache');
    UTL_HTTP.set_header (http_request, 'content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    UTL_HTTP.set_authentication (http_request, 'temp', 'temppass');

    UTL_HTTP.write_text (http_request,
                         'request_type=secure&scope=global&user_id=temp&password=temppass');

    http_response := UTL_HTTP.get_response (http_request);

    UTL_HTTP.read_text (http_response, return_text);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (return_text);
END;
/
```

Comment: Thanks EJ, but where or how do I set the parameters present within --data?

Comment: Just updated with an example. You would need to use `UTL_HTTP.WRITE_TEXT` to populate the body of the request.